# How to retain javascript toogle up and down

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following javascript to toggle up and the the table on button click. I want to retain the toggle up or down. I have an arrow next and previous. When the user click next arrow or previous arrow it will know if the table is toggle up or down. Would somebody tell how i can achieve this. Thank you

original code which is working fine but would not retain toggle up or down.

```
 jQuery('#btnHide').live('click', function(event) {        
           jQuery('#dataTable').toggle('show');
 });
```

previous button click

```
$("#previous_event_audio").on("click", function () {
            $($('#tabstrip').find('a.k-link')[4]).data('contentUrl', 'Product?eventId=@ViewBag.PrevEventId');
            var ts = $('#tabstrip').data("kendoTabStrip");
            ts.reload(".k-state-active");
        });
```

next button click

```
$("#next_event_audio").on("click", function () {
            $($('#tabstrip').find('a.k-link')[4]).data('contentUrl', 'Product?eventId=@ViewBag.NextEventId');
            var ts = $('#tabstrip').data("kendoTabStrip");
            ts.reload(".k-state-active");
        });
```

Thank you

Comment: as I know you better not use live(), but on()

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code or be more specific? There's not much to go off of here.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this? check DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/jYnc7/

## JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#show').click(function(){
        $('#myTable').slideDown(200);
    });
    $('#hide').click(function(){
        $('#myTable').slideUp(200);
    });
});
```

Comment: no. i need to retain the toggle up between previous or next button click

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle?